# preparedstatemnt in clause in spring batch

Tags: java, prepared-statement, spring-batch, in-clause, reader

Good day,

In spring batch reader, normally i will put a sql inside the reader.
eg.

```
<bean id="zReader" class="ibs.batch.job.reader.ZTableReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql"
        value="SELECT ZP.EMPLOYEEOLDIC, ZP.EMPLOYEENEWIC, ZP.EMPLOYEENAME, ZP.AMOUNT, ZP.ZAKATCODE
                      FROM S.ZPAYMENT ZP
                      WHERE ZP.DEDUCTIONMONTH = ? AND ZP.COMPANYREGNO = ?
                      AND ZP.MODIFIEDBY IS NULL " />
    <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="zReader" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="ibs.batch.job.reader.mapper.ZPaymentReaderTableMapper" />
    </property>
    <property name="saveState" value="false" />
</bean>
```

and then, in our reader java file, we will set the parameter like

```
@Override
public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
    ps.setString( 1, employerName );
    ps.setString( 2, monthOfContribution );
}
```

now i wish to change the query to

```
SELECT ZP.EMPLOYEEOLDIC, ZP.EMPLOYEENEWIC, ZP.EMPLOYEENAME, ZP.AMOUNT, ZP.ZAKATCODE
                        FROM S.ZPAYMENT ZP
                        WHERE ZP.UserId in (?)
```

and in reader java file,

```
String userIds = "'1871','1872'";
ps.setString( 1, userIds );
```

But I will keep hitting `SqlException`, which `SqlState` = 22018

Is this possible in spring batch?

Comment: I suspect this might be the issue with the line ps.setString( 1, "'1871','1872'" ); and thats possibly due to quotes mismatch. Try hard coding the values in the SQL n run to confirm that n then play with quotes for correct arrangement.

Comment: Tried, its working fine when I run the Sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is another better to do it.

Which is not to write the sql query in the `xml` file, write it in `beforeStep()` method in `ZTableReader` java file. In here, I can construct a `String` or `StringBuilder` to build my sql query flexible. And then user `setSql()` to set the `Sql` query.

Example code :

```
String sql = "Select * from tableA where .....";

setSql(sql);
```

And then put dummy value for the sql in `xml` file, for example:

```
<property name="sql" value="dummy" />
```

When come to `ZTableReader`'s `beforeStep()`, the "dummy" value will be override by the sql that I define.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a placeholder representing several values. The placeholder is not simply a place over which the the parameter value that you set later is copy pasted. In other words, the fact that it works if you replace `?` by `'1871','1872'` is irrelevant, because that's not what the jdbc driver does.

You actually need one placeholder per individual value, which means that if you want to send a varying number of values, you cannot use a single static SQL string. You'll have to come up with another strategy (say,  insert before the required values into a separate temporary table and then select from that temporary table in the insert statement, wrap one the classes in another that fixes the SQL statement before delegating to it, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the in query , If you already know the number of parameters that are to be provided with the in , then use it like

```
WHERE ZP.UserId in (?,?)

and p.setString(1,'1871') p.setString(2,'1871')
```

Else construct a sql query by appending the strings in the in and fire the query, as far as i know there is no decent solution to this issue with in queries and preparedstatement.